# Macro created in Excel 2010, shows complile error on other users machines

Tags: excel, macros

I have created a macro within Excel 2010 that saves the workbook with a file name created from a specific cell.

This works fine on my own machine, however when I give the file over to the end user it shows a compile error.

My code is :-

```
Sub autosave()

'SAVE FILE
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rtn = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(arg1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Calculator").Range("B15").Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Not rtn Then Cancel = True


'no file name
'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show


End Sub
```

The compile error shows : **"Cant Find project or library"**
then it debugs at: **rtn = Application.dialogs (xldialogsaveAs)…..**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error is not necessarily related to that line. What is `MISSING:` if you go to `Tools - References` on computers where it does not work?

Comment: It states that Microsoft Outlook 14.0 object library is missing?.  However the following are all version 14.0 on my 2010 version and 12.0 on other users systems:  **Microsoft Excel 12.0 object Library** & **Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library**

Comment: I have looked at the link that you have put on the top stating that this has been answered previously, however im not proficient in Macro, and don't fully understand how to A: **save the file under the earliest Office version**, when I am trying to save it as a macro enabled, and B: How to late bind into my code?

Comment: To save the file under the earliest Office version, you go to a computer with that Office version and save the file there. To switch your code to late binding, you remove your reference to Outlook from References and use `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` to instantiate Outlook.

Comment: thanks that has worked a treat!!! sorry for all the questions.  Thanks